# router Controller AngularJs Not working

Tags: angularjs

I've tried to get to know how to work with Angular but have no luck. I don't know what i do wrong.

Here is my index.html:

```html
<html ng-app="app">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>testAngular</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core/css/style.css">
  <script src="core/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="core/js/angularRoute.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Controllers/users.js"></script>
  <script src="Services/router.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <p class="well">
    <a href="#/">Home</a>
    <a href="#/users">Users</a>
    <a href="#/shop">Shop</a>
   </p>
   <h3>Users</h3>
   <hr class="vau">
   <form>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="search">
   </form>
   <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my router.js

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'tpl/home.html'
  })
  .when('/users', {
   templateUrl: 'tpl/users.html',
   controller: 'userCtrl'
  })
  .when('/shop', {
   templateUrl: 'tpl/shop.html'
  })
  .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Here is my users.js

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $http){
 $http.get('dataModel/users.json').then(function(res){
  $scope.users = res.data;
 });
});
```

and this is my users.html

```js
<h3>Hello Users</h3>
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
 <table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>
   <th>pId</th>
   <th>Vorname</th>
   <th>Nachname</th>
   <th>E-Mail</th>
   <th>Abteilung</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
    <td>{{user.pId}}</td>
    <td>{{user.fName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>{{user.abtelung}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<p>hello Users</p>
```

I don't know why the controller is not working. thank you very much for any idea and help.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
```

You are creating a new module named app, and overriding any existing module with the same name.

Instead, create the module once like that, and on other files when you want to retrieve the model, do it like:

```
angular.module('app')
```

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer. but unfortunately not working for me. it shows me alot of errors :(

Comment: i do this:  angular.module('app') in my controller